# FileNotFoundError for a properties file in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm getting a `FileNotFoundException` when I try to read a properties file in in my spring controller.

Here is the log that shows when and where it occurs:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\props\configFile.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at com.webclaims.translator.Translator.readPropertiesFile(Translator.java:65)
at com.webclaims.translator.Translator.createEditablePage(Translator.java:45)
at com.webclaims.translator.controllers.TestController.editableWebpage(TestController.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

The location of my properties file is `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/props/configFile.properties`

Here is the controller that has the `editableWebpage()` that is showed in the log:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit")
public ModelAndView editableWebpage() throws IOException {
    final String source = "http://localhost:8080/translator/test";
    final String target = "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/editable_webpage.jsp";
    final String config = "src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/props/configFile.properties";

    Translator t = new Translator();
    t.createEditablePage(source, target, config);

    return new ModelAndView("editable_webpage");
}
```

Then we go to my Java class that has the `createEditablePage()` that is seen in the log above:

```
@PropertySource(value = "configFile.properties")
public class Translator {

@Autowired
private Properties properties;

private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(Translator.class.getName());

public Translator() {
    this.properties = new Properties();
}

public Properties getProperties() {
    return properties;
}

public void setProperties(Properties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
}

public void createEditablePage(String source, String target, String config) {
    File file = new File(target);
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(source).get();
        Elements elements = doc.select("*");
        readPropertiesFile(config);
        for(Element element : elements) {
            if(!element.ownText().equals("")) {

                String key = getKeyFromPropertiesFile(element.text().toString());
                if(!key.equals("")) {
                    element.addClass(key);
                    element.attr("contentEditable", "true");
                }
            }
        }
        FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, doc.outerHtml(), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException has occured", e);
    }
}

private void readPropertiesFile(String config) {
    try {
        File propsFile = new File(config);
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(propsFile);
        properties.load(inputStream);
        inputStream.close();
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "FileNotFoundException has occured", e);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, "IOException has occured", e);     
    }
}
```

Here is what I have in my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
    <display-name>translator</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value> 
    </context-param> 
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My spring-servlet.xml contains two bean where one of them is telling spring about the properties file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"    
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"    
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd  
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc   
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/> 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.webclaims.*" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="propertiesFile" class="com.webclaims.translator.Translator">
    <property name="properties" value="/WEB-INF/props/configFile.properties"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Have you tried putting `configFile.properties` in resources folder?

Comment: How would I access it there? Is it something like `classpath:configFile.properties`?

Comment: yes. classpath:configFile.properties

Answer (score 0):

Your locations are mismatched!

In value attribute you specified value="/WEB-INF/props/configFile.properties"

but you mentioned that your file is at  "/WEB-INF/config/configFile.properties"

If you still facing issue try to put property file in src folder

Comment: That was a typo. It's now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

value="src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/props/configFile.properties"

Answer (score 0):

Oups, there are some misunderstanding of key concepts here...

*The location of my properties file is `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/props/configFile.properties`*. No. This is the location of the source of your property file. You have a build pass that will build a .war file, and that war file will be runned by a servlet container. At that moment (run time) all reference to source files have been lost.

The build process will (broadly speaking and assuming a maven build):

- compile all java files to class files and put them under /WEB-INF/classes
- copy all files from src/main/resources under /WEB-INF/classes where they will be accessible at run time as resources with `ClassLoader.getResource` or `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`
- copy all files from src/main/webapp directly under / and will be accessible at run time as resources with `ServletContext.getResource` or `ServletContext.getResourceAsStream`.

Using resources for read-only data is better, because you can transparently use resources that lives in the `META-INF/resources` folder of a jar deployed inside your application.

Anyway, if you really need to open a file of the web application, the only correct way is to use the method `ServletContext.getRealPath` to translate a path relative to the root of the application into an absolute path **on the server** (and no longer in the developper's source)

So to read the property file, you should get it as a ressource from the ServletContex:

- in you controller use the *relative* path and get the `InputStream`:

  ```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/edit")
  public ModelAndView editableWebpage(ServletRequest request) throws IOException {
      final String source = "http://localhost:8080/translator/test";
      final String config = "/WEB-INF/props/configFile.properties";
      ...
      InputStream inputStreamConfig = request.getServletContext()
          .getResourceAsStream(config);
      t.createEditablePage(source, target, inputStreamConfig);

      return new ModelAndView("editable_webpage");
  }
  ```
- in the `readPropertiesFile` method, just load the properties:

  ```
  properties.load(inputStreamConfig);
  ```

But there are other problems is your code:

- in `Translator` class you have both:

  ```
  @Autowired
  private Properties properties;
  ```

  meaning that properties should be injected, and

  ```
  public Translator() {
      this.properties = new Properties();
  }
  ```

  initializing it in constructor. **One is useless**.
- The `Translator` class uses `Autowired` annotation so it should be a Spring bean, but you create it with `new`. Do not do that but inject it in the controller
- In web.xml, you declare the same file for the root context **and** for the DispatcherServlet context => every bean will be created twice, once in each context. But you did not declare any ContextLoaderListener to bootstrap Spring. It is common to find this:

  ```
  <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  ```